# How can i design a square with broken border in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, border, shapes

I have to design a QR Code scanner widget and need to design something like this in flutter. I want to know if this is possible using the widgets and shapes baked into flutter.

[image: qr]

Comment: seems you need a `CustomPaint` widget